# Controls added dynamically not visible

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to add controls to WPF Grid dynamically basically to create a suduku layout, I have checked with Visual tree viewer in debug mode, controls are getting added to the Grid, but never updated on UI,

Can you please let me know if i am missing anything.. below is my code

```
    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)


     For _row As Integer = 0 To 9

        Dim rowDef As RowDefinition = New RowDefinition()


        If _row = 3 Or _row = 6 Then
            grdMain.Height = 25
        Else
            grdMain.Height = 20
        End If
            grdMain.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef)
        For _col As Integer = 0 To 9

            lblProgress.Content = _row.ToString()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

            Dim colDef As ColumnDefinition = New ColumnDefinition()


            If _col = 3 Or _col = 6 Then
                grdMain.Width = 25
            Else
                grdMain.Width = 20
            End If
                grdMain.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef)
            Dim tb As TextBox = New TextBox()
            tb.Name = "txtBox" & _row.ToString & _col.ToString
            tb.Text = tb.Name


            Grid.SetRowSpan(tb, 1)
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(tb, 1)

            grdMain.Children.Add(tb)

            Grid.SetRow(tb, _row)
            Grid.SetColumn(tb, _col)
        Next
    Next
    Me.Content = grdMain
    Me.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Create a proper `ItemsControl` and use proper DataBinding instead.

Comment: @HighCore, Not saying that in this particular case there is a legit reason to do it but can you tell me with 100% certainty that there can be no scenario where adding/manipulating controls in procedural code would be acceptable or perhaps even the only way of achieving something?

Comment: why are changing the height and width of grdMain ?
you probably meant to change the size of the column def. and row def. (plural)

Comment: @DeanK. yes, I'm 100% certain that procedural code is never "the only way" to achieve anything in XAML-based technologies. Use an `ItemsControl`. Period.

Comment: @HighCore Left the door open for acceptable? What if I rephrased "the only" to "the only feasible"? Don't get me wrong we're pretty much on the same page I just don't like claims of never and impossible... One thing I learned is that if there is something in the .NET framework there is usualy a good reason for it...

Comment: @DeanK. I have not seen to this day a single case where it would make more sense to use procedural code than proper XAML and DataBinding. If you know one please show that to me.

Comment: @HighCore, Let's say you have some EAV data and need to create a number of controls unknown in advance in order to display individual pieces of data (could be TB could be some very special UserControl or something completely different)... I'm not aware of a way of displaying at compile-time unknown number of controls using pure XAML... are you? Remember, this is EAV data, you might have to display 0, 1 or 1000 pieces of data, all in individual controls... there is no way of doing this in pure XAML that I am aware of...

Comment: Sure, in 99% of cases you could put that data in the DataGrid but there are legit cases where you'd have to put data values in highly specialized UserControl instances...

Comment: @DeanK. wrong. I don't know what `EAV` is but whatever Items-based UI (where you have a collection of items/data of unknown size) is done in WPF with an `ItemsControl`, regardless of their visual appearance (you define whatever `DataTemplate`s for each different data type with `DataTriggers` and whatnot). `DataGrid` is just a special type of `ItemsControl`, just as `ListBox`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that ItemsControl would solve any scenario with unknown number of items %99 percent of time, all I'm saying is that there are some scenarios where creating some UI control in a loop in procedural code might be the preferred way to go and no I don't have a full example at this time so let's leave it at this...

Comment: @DeanK. wrong. a winforms-like approach in never "preferred" or "better" or (depending who you ask) even acceptable in WPF. *"creating some UI control in a loop"* sounds like something my grandma would do 75 years ago in her XT computer with DOS 1.0. WPF is not winforms.

Comment: @DeanK. BTW, See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx) where it clearly states that using that approach effectively breaks UI Virtualization: *•Item containers are added directly to the ItemsControl. For example, if an application explicitly adds ListBoxItem objects to a ListBox, the ListBox does not virtualize the ListBoxItem objects...* - which makes your approach completely useless and inadequate in most cases when dealing with large collections of items.

Comment: So why did M$ spend the time and resources to allow us to have that capability in the first place... they don't waste money...

Comment: @DeanK. I really love your argument. the fact that something *can* be done is really a strong argument and proof that it *should* de done and that it is a *good idea* to do it. Nice. I'm presenting you with technical reasons for all my arguments and you come up with this.

Comment: @DeanK. BTW, the methods and capabilities to manually add items into an `ItemsControl` are probably being used internally by the DataBinding engine anyways. it was just a matter of changing `internal` to `public`. I don't see how that would represent an extra cost to anyone.

Comment: @HighCore Where did I say it should be done? Where did I say it's a good idea to do it? Show me? I said there could be some scenario where that would be acceptable or maybe even feasible, nowhere did I say it should be done on a regular basis so it is you who is coming up with conjectures...

Comment: @All , The only reason i am doing this in vb code instead of XAML is to assign "Name" for each textbox control. This will help me to access any textbox uniquely later..If there is a better way to do this.. please suggest. I know i can go to each textbox and assign name for 81 times..but i am looking for a better option

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried that before, not sure why you are not using xaml to achieve this.
But, can see essential part missing which is Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties of your label. This is required to position some content in the rows and columns you are creating.

for example, to position tb textbox in row 2 and column 4, you will need to do:

```
tb.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty,2);
tb.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty,4);
```

or

```
Grid.SetRow(tb, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(tb, 4);
```

Comment: Hi, i am already using Grid.SetRow(tb,2) and I am doing this in code because if u see, i want to generate 9*9 = 81 textboxes, i am creating a suduku applicatoin..I need to assign id for each element, to access that later, so i am trying to achieve this through code

Comment: Okay. Will have to run the code to see what could be missing, nothing else seems obvious to me.